# If $P$ is a prime ideal of a commutative ring $R$, then $R[x]/P[x]$ is isomorphic to $(R/P)[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a commutative ring $R$ with 1, and a prime ideal $P$. Then I have read that $R[x]/P[x]$ is isomorphic to $(R/P)[x]$.

I am not totally sure what either of these two objects are, I am imagining that

$R[x]/P[x] = \{ r(x) + P[x] | r(x) \in R[x] \}$,

and
$(R/P)[x]\ = \{ (r + P)[x] | r \in R \}$

but I am not sure. Further I am not sure what the map between these two sets should be before I prove it is a bijective homomorphism.

Additionally, since ideals are not necessarily subrings, is $P[x]$ even necessarily defined?

Comment: You are correct on the first one. For the second one, it is polynomials with coefficients in $R/P$. So you have expressions of the form $(a_0+P) + (a_1+P)x + \cdots + (a_n+P)x^n$, with addition and product of coefficients done modulo $p$, and the polynomial above being equal to the polynomial $(b_0+P) + \cdots + (b_m+P)x^m$ if and only if $b_i\equiv a_i\pmod{P}$ for all $i$ (extending by zeroes if necessary).

Comment: The easiest way to prove the isomorphism is to find a ring map from $R[x]$ to $(R/P)[x]$ whose kernel is $P[x]$. Or, to fully use universal properties, find a map from $R$ to $(R/P)$; extend that to a map into $(R/P)[x]$, then decide where to map $x$ (which should be obvious) to get a map from $R[x]$ to $(R/P)[x]$, and make sure the kernel is exactly $P[x]$.

Comment: There's an obvious surjective map $R[x] \to (R/P)[x]$.  FInd its kernel.

Comment: An ideal is a subring without identity, and as such the ring of polynomials with coefficients in a non-unital ring is defined, for example take the non-unital ring $2\mathbb Z$ and form $2\Bbb Z[X]$, which is the set of all polynomials having coefficients in $2\mathbb Z$. Now, by the identification above, $\Bbb Z(x) / 2 \Bbb Z[x] = (\Bbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)[x]$ i.e. the quotient is  the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ i.e. $0$ or $1$. For the proof of the identity given, use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I made a mistake defining $R[x]/P[x]$, should it not be
f(x)+P[x] where $f$ is in $R[x]$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг do you not mean any proper ideal is a subring without identity?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Right, a *proper* ideal is a nonunital subring. Also, most of these simple isomorphisms like this one will follow from the three isomorphism theorems, which is why you should know them well.

Comment: @IntegraThis: I’m having a hard time seeing the original that I replied to; if you had $P[x]$ instead of $R[x]$ as the set from which the original elements are taken, then yes, that was a mistake/typo.

Comment: I think your $R$ is missing an identity elemen for it to be a ring isomoprhism.

Comment: @IAmNoOne my textbook always assumes a $1_R$ but I added it anyway.

Comment: is your question answered now (by yourself) or is there a lingering question unanswered?

Comment: @IAmNoOne its answered, but I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $\theta:R[x] \to (R/P)[x]$ defined by 
$$ \theta:(a_0+\cdots+a_n x^n)\rightarrow (a_0 + P) + \cdots + (a_n +P)x^n.$$ 
Then the kernel of $\theta$ is $P[x]$. The map is clearly onto.

Afterwards applying the first isomorphism theorem will yield the result.

Comment: Your $\theta$ won't be one-to-one.  That's almost the point.

Comment: I think you mean "the kernel contains $P[x]$. Showing that it is exactly $P[x]$ gives an isomorphism."

Comment: @ElliotG ok right, will add that after I figure it out one side of the inclusion.

Comment: @ElliotG well by contradiction, if the k'th coefficient is not in $P$, then the k'th coefficient will be $(r+P)x^k \neq (0+P)x^k $, which is non-zero in (R/P)[x]?